# How to call functions on other computers?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, networking

Is there a way to call a function to run on all instances of a [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) application across a LAN?

I have an application which contains a dashboard of their own Joblist. I want another user on another PC to create and allocate a job to this user. Once created and saved, I would like the method `GetJobs();` to refresh. I've not done anything this advanced yet, so please go easy :)

Comment: A function in a program on another computer is a big jump in itself.  There at lots of things that consider: Firewalls, the user account that the program is running in.  What kind of *interface* you are going to use to call a function in the program.

One optinon is to not use WinForms but set up a "service" on the computers to handle the function.  At the very least, a WinForms program would need to have some kind of listener set up (TCP Socket) or Remote Procedure Call or Pipe set up.  The kind of interface should be designed with thought.

Comment: @ChrisWalsh: All those considerations have been done and solved almost 2 decades ago. The technology is called [COM or DCOM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366757.aspx) (see also [History of DCOM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6zzy7zky.aspx)) and implements all the facilities necessary to make remote procedure calls as easy as local procedure calls. All the proxying and marshaling is done automatically.

Comment: @IInspectable, did you mean to address me or the original poster?

Comment: @ChrisWalsh: I meant to address your last comment, that lists problems that have been solved 2 decades ago.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realise I was suggesting that my solutions were in any way new (TCP is much older than 20 years).  I was just responding to the question posed.

Answer (score 3):

Chris Walsh has excellent advice in his comment. That said, it is possible for Windows Forms applications to communicate with each other, and the simplest method, for me anyway, is [WCF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Communication_Foundation), self-hosted server. Typically the server code will not be running in the UI thread -- at least I don't recommend it. In fact, all WCF is best kept running in a background thread in a Windows Forms application, to avoid blocking the UI. WCF has lots of error conditions you will need to handle.

Another thing you might want to look at is MSMQ, now called Message Queueing. It can store a queue of jobs for you, and it won't lose them if the power is lost.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have some [SQL Server Express Edition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Express) installed as the database backend.

This way you can connect to the database using some authentication, and add the job's directly there.

Then on the other computer, add a refresh button or poll for changes. This has the advantage that you don't need to write a service by yourself, and jobs can be created even if the user is not there and his PC is switched off.

You need just one server which hosts the database.